# Windows 8 Volume Shadow Copy and Arch Linux

Tags: linux, windows-8, backup, arch-linux

Guys I'm with a problem regarding the backup of my windows 8 machine. It fails reporting:

> "A shadow copy could not be created. Pleasse check 'VSS' and 'SPP'
>   application event logs for more information. Details: Insufficient
>   storage available to create either the shadow copy storage file or
>   other shadow copy data." Error code: 0x81000019

I know that it says that there isn't enough space, but that is not the case. A interesting thing is it started to fail when I set up syslinux again to boot my archlinux. It is likely the fact it was written to mbr somehow borked my windows backups. If the mbr is clean it works again. What should I do?

Can it be considered a viable solution?
http://mlevit.wordpress.com/2009/11/25/a-shadow-copy-could-not-be-created-insufficient-storage-available-to-create-0x81000019/

Comment: Windows 8 increased it to 300mb so just make the portion larger...

Comment: @Ramhound it was working fine prior ive re-enabled the load of sysvinit from mbr. The partition has 500MB so I assume this is not the problem.